# Access functions from other .as files

Tags: flash, actionscript, static-methods

Okay, so I'm building a small game in AS3, and I have a lot of helper functions, so I've created Helper.as, just to clean it up.

Now, my problem is that I'm not allowed to access these functions.
Here is what I have so far.

Helper.as

```
//
public static function colorTransformer(obj, color)
{
   var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
   colorTransform.color = color;
   obj.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
}
```

And calling the function in Main.as

```
import Helpers;

Helpers.colorTransformer(myObj, myColorVar);
```

ERRORS:

Helpers.as, Line 24 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ColorTransform.
Helpers.as, Line 24 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method ColorTransform.

Comment: No error message, no answer possible.

Comment: Sorry, forgot. I've added the errors

Comment: Maybe you must import the flash.geom.ColorTransform package in Helper.as

Comment: Please check your question for consistency. You list 'Helper.as' and then 'import Helpers'. Please check that everything is correct.

Comment: @Sam DeHaan: there's no need for the .as suffix. Moreover, if that class is in the same folder there's no need for the import too.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns: I was confused by the poster's reference to 'Helper.as' before the source he provided, and then the Helpers class he used. Was attempting to figure out if it was a typo, or if he's not providing enough information.

Comment: I figured it out. thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Your Class in which You are imported Healper class like this:

```
package  
{
import Healper;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip      
{
    public function Main() 
    {
        Healper.colorTransformer(stage,0x00000);
    }
}   
}
```

and your Healper.as should be like this:

```
package  {
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

public class Healper {

    public function Healper() 
    {
        // constructor code
    }

    public static function colorTransformer(obj, color)
    {
       var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
       colorTransform.color = color;
       obj.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
    }
}   
}
```